# Работа с Word из приложения

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста почему параметр "Копировать локально" в Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word не хочет включатся, чего то не хватает?
[image: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса следует, что вы ссылаетесь на COM-assembly. Для них ссылка обычно добавляется с установкой `Embed Interop Types = true` (это видно и на вашем скриншоте). Вследствие этого COM-assembly линкуется прямо в вашу DLL, так что её не нужно копировать (и отдельно устанавливать при инсталляции на машине юзера).

Майкрософтовская документация по теме:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409610.aspx

Если вы всё же хотите более неудобный вариант (с копированием), пропишите `Embed Interop Types = false`, тогда поле `Copy Local` будет снова доступно.

<sub>Адаптация ответа к вопросу [Why is the Copy Local property for my reference disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526491/why-is-the-copy-local-property-for-my-reference-disabled)</sub>